# Drm video stops after 2 minutes of playing

Tags: drm, cobalt

Cobalt 19.lts.2.188191. I am used default implementation of Widevine L3. After 2-3 minutes the DRM video playing stops. This issue manifests itself in the following videos:

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=jIStmjA2M24

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=g5jbF_H72NA

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=mTaP9_cumoE

These videos were provided to us by a YouTube account manager.

The log after 2 minutes of playing:

```
...
[ERROR:core/src/cdm_engine.cpp(1406):Decrypt] CdmEngine::Decrypt: session not found: Empty session ID
[ERROR:cdm/src/cdm.cpp(999):decrypt] Key not available.
[ERROR:core/src/cdm_engine.cpp(1406):Decrypt] CdmEngine::Decrypt: session not found: Empty session ID
[ERROR:cdm/src/cdm.cpp(999):decrypt] Key not available.
...
```

Comment: Hi, please, can you post your code? Thank you

Comment: Hi, I am using existing code from starboard/shared/widevine/drm_system_widevine.h.

Answer (score 0):

Do you support DRM key rotation? Those videos rotate the keys every two minutes. Please take a look at YouTube's EME section of Technical Requirements.

Comment: I am used implementation Widevine from starboard/shared/widevine/drm_system_widevine.h. It supports DRM key rotation?

Comment: There is a test https://yt-media-test.appspot.com/2018.html?test_type=encryptedmedia-test&tests=6. It pass successful.

Comment: Can you give us a log with lines contains "MediaKeyStatusMap::Add()"?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JMGYe-nUjmalSqvT8hYxM51T-r_xUOVs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @xiaoming, do I need to attach more logs or enough?

Comment: It could be an issue of our server.  I am going to create an internal bug to track it.  I will keep you updated once there is any progressive, but expect delays.

Comment: @xiaoming, do you have any news on this issue?

Comment: @AlexeyLukin, do you still have the issue?

Comment: @xiaoming, got better. But the problem still repeats. Now the video stops playing only after 6 - 12 key rotates. After 6-12 successfully key rotates, the video stops and rotation stops.

Comment: Alexey, the video keeps creating new sessions every 2 minutes without destroying them.  On some systems, there are limit on the number of concurrent sessions to be created. After the limit is reached, the creation of new sessions will fail.  In such case, the implementation should pass an error via |SbDrmSessionUpdateRequestFunc|.  Our JS player will handle this error, and restart the playback from the current position.